# ¿Cómo solventar el error de la clase SpreadsheetLight de C#?

Tags: c#, excel

les cuento tengo un aplicativo en C# y lo que deseo hacer es crear un archivo Excel, he investigado que se puede realizar con la clase SpreadsheetLight. a continuación coloco el fragmento de código:

```
using SpreadsheetLight;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CreacionDeExcelSinOffice
{
    class CreadorExcel
    {

        private string rutaArchivoCompleta = "";

        public CreadorExcel(string nombreArchivo)
        {
            //obtenemos la ruta de nuestro programa y concatenamos el nombre del archivo a crear
            rutaArchivoCompleta = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/" + nombreArchivo;

        }

        public void CrearExcel()
        {
            try
            {
                //creamos el objeto SLDocument el cual creara el excel
                SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();

                //creamos las celdas en diagonal
                //utilizando la función setcellvalue pueden navegar sobre el documento
                //primer parametro es la fila el segundo la columna y el tercero el dato de la celda
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) sl.SetCellValue(i, i, "patito " + i);

                //Guardar como, y aqui ponemos la ruta de nuestro archivo
                sl.SaveAs(rutaArchivoCompleta);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ocurrio una Excepción: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Este código me genera el siguiente error:

> Error 2   The type 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.InlineString' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. C:\Users\Stalin\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\CreacionDeExcelSinOffice.cs 31  47  ConsoleApplication1

De la siguiente línea

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) sl.SetCellValue(i, i, "patito " + i);
```

Si alguien sabe a que se debe o que estoy haciendo mal, les agradeceré su ayuda.

Comment: ¿No te faltará agregar las referencias: `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;`?

Comment: Tienes que instalar la siguiente versión DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.5.0, eso solventa el error que te esta arrojando. Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml -Version 2.5.0 Aquí puedes encontrar la documentación de la dll https://libraries.io/nuget/DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Comment: quizás les puede interesar probar esta nueva versión de SpreadsheetLight que permite utilizar la versión actualizada de DocumentFormat.OpenXml 2.11.3. - https://www.nuget.org/packages/asereware.spreadsheetlight

Comment: probar en maquina clente con el instalador este instala tambien las dlls del SpreadsheetLight

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes tener cuidado con la versión de `OpenXml` ya que las últimas versiones de SpreadsheetLight (a partir de la 3.4.7) solo sirven con la versión `2.5.0` de OpenXml.

Con base en el error que te está dando, debes tener una versión anterior de `SpreadsheetLight` ya que te está pidiendo una versión `2.0` de OpenXml, para comprobarlo sigue estos pasos:

1. En tu proyecto de Visual Studio ve al menú `Herramientas > Administrador de paquetes NuGet > Administrar paquetes NuGet para la solución...`.
2. En la pestaña **Instalado** busca "SpreadsheetLight" y dale clic al paquete. En el panel del lado derecho marca tu proyecto y te debe indicar abajo una **Descripción**, **Versión**, **Dependencias** entre otros.
3. En la descripción de `SpreadsheetLight` indica la dependencia del paquete de `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` necesaria.
4. Busca el paquete de `OpenXML` en el panel de la izquierda, da clic al paquete y verifica que en el panel derecho, en el campo **Instalado** este sea la versión que necesita `SpreadsheetLight`. Si no lo es, selecciónalo de la lista de versiones y dale clic a "Instalar".
5. Acepta todo lo que te pregunte, vuelve a compilar y ejecutar tu código.

Espero que esto te ayude.

Comment: Gracias efectivamente era la versión tenia la 2.5 he instalado la 2.0 y ahora funcionó correctamente. gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que así haya sido, no olvides marcar la respuesta como la solución a tu problema para cerrarla!

Answer (score 1):

Agrega una referencia al ensamblado de WindowsBase
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, te cuento que ya agregue la referencia y aún me sale el error, por otro lado no se si tenga que ver que el aplicativo esta desarrollado en C# 2010 Express

Comment: Creo que no importa, volviste a recompilar el proyecto?

Comment: sabes que version del DocumentFormat.OpenXml  tienes?

Comment: Claro volví a recompilar y me genera el error, la verdad no se que versión tenga, disculpa soy nuevo con c# ya voy a revisar y ver como puedo ver la versión

Comment: Si efectivamente era la versión tenia la versión 2.5 y no funcionaba he instalado la versión 2.0 y se resolvio el problema me ha generado el excell gracias

Comment: ¡En hora buena! @StalinCaiche

Answer (score 1):

Prueba de la  siguiente manera:

`rutaArchivoCompleta = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "nombredearchivo.xlsx";`

Así me funciona a mi.
Lo que haces con  ese código  es decirle a  tu programa que busque en el "dominio" (ruta) actual (donde se  guarda tu programa) el nombre del archivo  especifico.
Como  siempre se crea y se guarda en Debug (carpeta). Ahí  se guardará tu archivo  excel